# SELECT materializecssCSS

Tags: javascript, html, select, materialize

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#doc_rul').formSelect();
    $('#saveBut').click(function(){
        var instance = M.FormSelect.getInstance($('#doc_rul'));
        var _d = instance.getSelectedValues();
        console.log(_d);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col l5">
  <select name="doc_rul" id="doc_rul" class="doc_rul">
    <option value="1" selected="">Только для меня</option>
    <option value="2">Для всей организации</option>
    <option value="3">Вообще для всех</option>
  </select>
  <label class="" for="doc_rul">Права доступа</label>
</div>
<div class="col l5">
    <button name="saveBut" type="button" id="saveBut" class="btn btn-success ">Сохранить</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

shows the correct values if you select the value of the select twice

how to be

### И по русски

суть дела:

выводятся правильные значения только если дважды выбрать значение, а иначе выводятся значения предыдущего выбора

Comment: Can you translate the russian to english please? Also, if you want, there is https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: "shows the correct values if you select the value of the select twice how to be" = "И по русски суть дела выводятся правильные значения только если дважды выбрать значение, а иначе выводятся значения предыдущего выбора"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was enough to initialize the form once again and earn

`

```
$('#saveBut').click(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
    var instance = M.FormSelect.getInstance($('#doc_rul'));
    var _d = instance.getSelectedValues();
    console.log(_d);
});
```

`